# Capture image with Scoped Directory Access on Nougat

Tags: android, android-file, android-7.0-nougat, android-fileprovider, android-storage

I am trying to take image from camera with Scoped Directory Access, but it gives me following exception as follows,

```
    java.io.IOException: Permission denied
    09-22 22:43:40.556 23767-23767/mp.wall.client W/System.err:     at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
09-22 22:43:40.556 23767-23767/mp.wall.client W/System.err:     at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:280)
09-22 22:43:40.556 23767-23767/mp.wall.client W/System.err:     at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:948)
09-22 22:43:40.556 23767-23767/mp.wall.client W/System.err:     at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1862)
09-22 22:43:40.557 23767-23767/mp.wall.client W/System.err:     at mp.wall.utility.imageCapturePickerCompressor.ImageCapture.getCameraPicturesLocation(ImageCapture.java:91)
09-22 22:43:40.557 23767-23767/mp.wall.client W/System.err:     at mp.wall.utility.imageCapturePickerCompressor.ImageCapture.createCameraPictureFile(ImageCapture.java:64)
09-22 22:43:40.557 23767-23767/mp.wall.client W/System.err:     at mp.wall.utility.imageCapturePickerCompressor.ImageCapture.createCameraIntent(ImageCapture.java:50)
09-22 22:43:40.557 23767-23767/mp.wall.client W/System.err:     at mp.wall.utility.imageCapturePickerCompressor.ImageCapture.openCamera(ImageCapture.java:116)
09-22 22:43:40.557 23767-23767/mp.wall.client W/System.err:     at mp.wall.ui.dashboard.viewInfo.personalInfo.editProfile.EditProfile.onActivityResult(EditProfile.java:219)
09-22 22:43:40.557 23767-23767/mp.wall.client W/System.err:     at mp.wall.ui.dashboard.viewInfo.personalInfo.editProfile.imagePickerDialog.ImagePickerDialogFragment.sideMenuItem(ImagePickerDialogFragment.java:65)
09-22 22:43:40.557 23767-23767/mp.wall.client W/System.err:     at mp.wall.ui.dashboard.viewInfo.personalInfo.editProfile.imagePickerDialog.ItemAdapter$VHItem.onClick(ItemAdapter.java:58)
09-22 22:43:40.557 23767-23767/mp.wall.client W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6205)
09-22 22:43:40.557 23767-23767/mp.wall.client W/System.err:     at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11103)
09-22 22:43:40.557 23767-23767/mp.wall.client W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23653)
09-22 22:43:40.557 23767-23767/mp.wall.client W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
09-22 22:43:40.558 23767-23767/mp.wall.client W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
09-22 22:43:40.558 23767-23767/mp.wall.client W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
09-22 22:43:40.558 23767-23767/mp.wall.client W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
09-22 22:43:40.558 23767-23767/mp.wall.client W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-22 22:43:40.558 23767-23767/mp.wall.client W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1534)
09-22 22:43:40.558 23767-23767/mp.wall.client W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1424)
```

as per the [documentation of google](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/scoped-directory-access.html), it is an alternative of Requesting READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE or WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in your manifest, my code work great below Naugat but since i had removed these permission for Naugat and used Scoped Directory Access but it throws the above mentioned error.

Following is my fragment code,

```
package mp.wall.ui.dashboard.viewInfo.personalInfo.editProfile;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.storage.StorageManager;
import android.os.storage.StorageVolume;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.RoundedBitmapDrawable;
import android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.target.BitmapImageViewTarget;

import java.io.File;

import mp.wall.R;
import mp.wall.controllers.constants.NumericEnums;
import mp.wall.controllers.constants.RestConstants;
import mp.wall.ui.dashboard.viewInfo.personalInfo.editProfile.imagePickerDialog.ImagePickerDialogFragment;
import mp.wall.utility.AndroidVersions;
import mp.wall.utility.ContextFunction;
import mp.wall.utility.IMPermission;
import mp.wall.utility.Intents;
import mp.wall.utility.imageCapturePickerCompressor.ImageCapture;
import   mp.wall.utility.imageCapturePickerCompressor.ImageCapturePickerCallbacks;
import tr004.libraryutils.LogUtil;

public class EditProfile extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener, ImageCapturePickerCallbacks {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit_profile, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    ImageView imgBack = ContextFunction.findViewByIdAndCast(view, R.id.hb_img_back);
    imgBack.setOnClickListener(this);

    TextView tvTitle = ContextFunction.findViewByIdAndCast(view, R.id.hb_tv_title);
    tvTitle.setText(ContextFunction.getStringResource(context, R.string.edit_info_profile_title));
    tvTitle.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);

    TextView tvSave = ContextFunction.findViewByIdAndCast(view, R.id.hb_tv_action);
    tvSave.setText(ContextFunction.getStringResource(context, R.string.edit_info_profile_save));
    ContextFunction.viewShow(tvSave);
    tvSave.setOnClickListener(this);

    ImageView imgCam = ContextFunction.findViewByIdAndCast(view, R.id.fep_img_camGallery);
    imgCam.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button btChangePassword = ContextFunction.findViewByIdAndCast(view, R.id.fep_bt_changePassword);
    btChangePassword.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.fep_img_camGallery:
            if(AndroidVersions.isNaugatOrHighier())
            {
                StorageManager sm = (StorageManager)context.getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);
                StorageVolume volume = sm.getPrimaryStorageVolume();
                Intent intent = volume.createAccessIntent(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 2001);
            }else
                openGalleryAndCamera();
            break;
    }
}

private void openGalleryAndCamera() {
    String[] perms = {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
    if (IMPermission.hasPermissions(this, perms))
        showImagePickerDialogFragment();
    else
        IMPermission.requestPermissions(this, ContextFunction.getStringResource(context,
                R.string.perm_common, R.string.perm_camera_read_write),
                NumericEnums.PermissionConstant.CAMERA_GALLERY.getCode(), perms);
}

private void showImagePickerDialogFragment()
{
    ImageCapture.openCamera(this, this);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    NumericEnums.PermissionConstant permissionConstant = NumericEnums.PermissionConstant.fromRepresentation(requestCode);
    switch (permissionConstant) {
        case CAMERA_GALLERY:
            if (ContextFunction.checkAllPermisssionGranterd(permissions, grantResults))
                openGalleryAndCamera();
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch(requestCode) {
        case 2001:
            if (Activity.RESULT_OK == resultCode ) {
                showImagePickerDialogFragment();
            }else
                LogUtil.e("per","permisson not granted");
            break;
        default:
            ImageCapture.handleActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode, data, this, this);
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void success(File file) {
    Glide.with(context).asBitmap().load(file).into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(imgPic) {
        @Override
        protected void setResource(Bitmap resource) {
            RoundedBitmapDrawable circularBitmapDrawable =
                    RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(getResources(),
                            resource);
            circularBitmapDrawable.setCircular(true);
            imgPic.setImageDrawable(circularBitmapDrawable);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onImagePickerError(Exception e, NumericEnums.DeviceFeaturesCons source) {
    ContextFunction.showToast(context, R.string.field_select, R.string.image_selectin_error);
}

@Override
public void onCanceled(NumericEnums.DeviceFeaturesCons source) {
    File photoFile = ImageCapture.lastlyTakenButCanceledPhoto(context);
    if (photoFile != null)
        photoFile.delete();
}

@Override
public void onError(String msg) {
    showToast("simple error");
}
```

}

Following is my IMageCapture file as follows,

```
package mp.Wall.utility.imageCapturePickerCompressor;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

import mp.Wall.BuildConfig;
import mp.Wall.controllers.constants.NumericEnums;
import mp.Wall.data.sPrefs.StorageManager;
import mp.Wall.utility.ContextFunction;
import mp.Wall.utility.Validation;

public class ImageCapture
{
private static final String KEY_PHOTO_URI = "thGreat004.photopicker.photo_uri";
private static final String KEY_LAST_CAMERA_PHOTO = "thGreat004.photopicker.last_photo";

private static Intent createCameraIntent(@NonNull Object object, ImageCapturePickerCallbacks imageCapturePickerCallback) {
    Context context= ContextFunction.getActivity(object);

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    try {
        Uri capturedImageUri = createCameraPictureFile(context);
        //We have to explicitly grant the write permission since Intent.setFlag
        // works only on API Level >=20
        grantWritePermission(context, intent, capturedImageUri);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, capturedImageUri);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        imageCapturePickerCallback.onError("errorOccured");
    }

    return intent;
}

public static Uri createCameraPictureFile(@NonNull Context context) throws IOException {
    File imagePath = getCameraPicturesLocation();
    Uri uri = getUriToFile(context, imagePath);

    StorageManager storageManager = StorageManager.getInstance(context);
    storageManager.setValue(KEY_PHOTO_URI, uri.toString());
    storageManager.setValue(KEY_LAST_CAMERA_PHOTO, imagePath.toString());

    return uri;
}

private static void grantWritePermission(@NonNull Context context, Intent intent, Uri uri) {
    List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent,
            PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
        String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
        context.grantUriPermission(packageName, uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION |
                Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    }
}

private static void revokeWritePermission(@NonNull Context context, Uri uri) {
    context.revokeUriPermission(uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION |
            Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
}

private static File getCameraPicturesLocation() throws IOException {
    File dir = imageDirectory();
    return File.createTempFile(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), ".jpg", dir);
}

private static Uri getUriToFile(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull File file) {
    String authority = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".Wall.fileprovider";
    return FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, authority, file);
}

public static void openCamera(Fragment fragment, ImageCapturePickerCallbacks imageCapturePickerCallback) {
    Intent intent = createCameraIntent(fragment, imageCapturePickerCallback);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (!Validation.isNull(intent.resolveActivity(fragment.getContext().getPackageManager()))) {
        fragment.startActivityForResult(intent, NumericEnums.DeviceFeaturesCons.CAMERA
                .getCode());
    }else
        imageCapturePickerCallback.onError("No app is installed to handle camera");
    // ContextFunction.showToast(activity, R.string.intents_no_app_common, R.string.cons_gallery);
}

public static void handleActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data,
                                        Object object, ImageCapturePickerCallbacks imageCapturePickerCallback) {
    {
        if (Activity.RESULT_OK == resultCode) {
            if (NumericEnums.DeviceFeaturesCons.CAMERA.getCode() == requestCode) {
                onPictureReturnedFromCamera(object, imageCapturePickerCallback);
            }
        }
        else if (Activity.RESULT_CANCELED == resultCode){
            if (NumericEnums.DeviceFeaturesCons.CAMERA.getCode() == requestCode)
                imageCapturePickerCallback.onCanceled(NumericEnums.DeviceFeaturesCons.CAMERA);
        }
    }
}

private static void onPictureReturnedFromCamera(Object object,ImageCapturePickerCallbacks imageCapturePickerCallback) {
    Activity activity= ContextFunction.getActivity(object);

    String lastImageUri = StorageManager.getInstance(activity).getValue(KEY_PHOTO_URI, null);
    if (!Validation.isEmpty(lastImageUri))
        revokeWritePermission(activity, Uri.parse(lastImageUri));
    File photoFile = takenCameraPicture(activity);

    if (Validation.isNull(photoFile)) {
        Exception e = new IllegalStateException("Unable to get the picture " +
                "returned from camera");
        imageCapturePickerCallback.onImagePickerError(e, NumericEnums.DeviceFeaturesCons.CAMERA);
    } else
        compressImage(photoFile,imageCapturePickerCallback);

    clearPhotoStorate(activity);
}

private static void compressImage(File file,ImageCapturePickerCallbacks imageCapturePickerCallback)
{
    imageCapturePickerCallback.success(file);
}

public static void clearPhotoStorate(Context context)
{
    StorageManager.getInstance(context).removeValue(KEY_LAST_CAMERA_PHOTO);
    StorageManager.getInstance(context).removeValue(KEY_PHOTO_URI);
}

private static File imageDirectory() {
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "Wall");

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d("sdf", "Oops! Failed create "
                    + "Wall" + " directory");
            return null;
        }
    }
    return mediaStorageDir;
}

@Nullable
private static File takenCameraPicture(Context context){
    String lastCameraPhoto = StorageManager.getInstance(context).getValue(KEY_LAST_CAMERA_PHOTO, null);
    if (!Validation.isEmptyorNull(lastCameraPhoto))
        return new File(lastCameraPhoto);
    else
        return null;
}

/**
 * @param context context
 * @return File containing lastly taken (using camera) photo. Returns null if
 * there was no photo taken or it doesn't exist anymore.
 */
public static File lastlyTakenButCanceledPhoto(@NonNull Context context) {
    String filePath =StorageManager.getInstance(context).getValue(KEY_LAST_CAMERA_PHOTO, null);
    if (filePath == null)
        return null;
    File file = new File(filePath);
    if (file.exists())
        return file;
    else
        return null;
}
```

}

Here is My manifest file as follows,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="23"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="23"/>

<application
    android:label="Wall"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".ui.splash.SplashActivity"
        android:noHistory="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.wall.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
    </provider>
</application>
```

and last this is my filepath.xml as follows,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
  <external-path name="WallParkImages" path="DCIM/Wall" />
</paths>
```

Comment: `I am trying to take image from camera with Scoped Directory Access`. You could have explained first how you try to do that as it is not needed to take an image with the camera. You suppose we dig through all that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the `File` class to create a file working with the Storage Access Framework.

You should use `DocumentFile.createFile()`.

Comment: can u please elaborate the answer as  i am not able to see the example

Comment: Which example ?

Comment: means any example on web

Comment: So you are unable to find an example how to create a file using DocumentFile and SAF?

Comment: no, i mean to say, i want the answer of above question with this DocumentFile

Comment: If you can find examples then what is exactly the problem?

Comment: first thanks for your assistance, i just wanted to use this framework for capturing image from camera, can u please help?

Comment: i am using your hint to sort out the issue

Comment: Yes i helped you by telling to use DocumentFile. And if you found examples to create files then what is the problem exactly? Please first explain what you have in mind. How should all work. You did not tell at all. You expect us  that to understand from your code?